# Does the law of large numbers contradict independent probability (when rolling a dice lets say)

Tags: probability

Does the law of large numbers contradict independent probability (when rolling a dice lets say) because I have been wondering why the more rolls you make more closely represent the expected probability if each roll is independent of the last ?

Comment: The law of large numbers is stated in terms of the expected value after averaging many events. It does not say anything about single events (see here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law)

Comment: That's the same as the "ever-green" mis-conception of delayed numbers in lottery: do you know where the fault lies in this case ?

Comment: Recall that the statement of the Law of Large Numbers says that the variables it concerns are _independent_ and identically distributed, and the theorem's proof follows from that assumption. Note that the theorem doesn't claim that the aggregate result of all the rolls will ever match the expected probability exactly. In the long run, it doesn't matter what happened on the 7th roll, or the 77th, or the 777th.